# Java - Access to non-static properties with reflection

Tags: java

I want to get my class property with string name.
I have a code like this

```
class Test
{
    public String simple = "hello";

    public void getSetting()
    {
        try
        {
            Test c = new Test();
            Class cls = this.getClass();
            Field field = cls.getField("simple");;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // error
        }

    }
}
```

I get an error with this code , because my property is non-static , and when i changing my property to static , it's work fine , how can i get non-static properties with reflection?

Comment: create a method in your test class to do the work.  Instantiate the class and call the method.

Comment: BTW what is `public main ()`  ?

Comment: "public main()" this should not compile, either you mean public static void main() or you mean public Test()

Comment: so ,can you share your code?

Comment: What ? You do not use `c`.  Also never ignore Exceptions

Comment: Yes, i forget using c :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a self-contained example on how to get an instance `Field` through reflection.

```
public class Main {
    // the instance field
    String simple = "foo";
    // some static main method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // initializing the class as we're accessing an instance method
        new Main().reflect();
    }

    public void reflect() {
        Class<?> c = this.getClass();
        try {
            // using getDeclaredField for package-protected / private fields
            Field field = c.getDeclaredField("simple");
            // printing out field's value for this instance
            System.out.println(field.get(this));
        }
        // TODO handle better
        catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
            iae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException n) {
            n.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    Test c = new Test();
    Class cls = c.getClass();              //Change this.getClass to c.getClass()
    Field field = cls.getField("simple");;
}
```

The Field must be static or belong to a instance that can be get via reflection.